# Can an iPhone App create and send + receive and read a CSV file as an ATTACHMENT?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to introduce a feature in my iPhone App that allows the following:
1) creating and sending by email a CSV file from within my iPhone App.
2) importing into my iPhone App a CSV file created with 3rd party software and sent to me by email.

These are the questions:
1a) Is it possible to actually create a CSV file from within the App and send it as an attachment? I know I can send an email containing all the strings required, but I want to be able to send the actual file. 
1b) Once created, can this file be stored into the memory allocated to my iPhone App?
2) What procedure should I follow to import a CSV file into my App? I do not want to read the CSV file from a URL.
Can all this be done with the iPhone or not??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1a) Yes, you can use the `addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` method on an instance of the `MFMailComposeViewController` class to do that.

1b) Yes, you can write the `NSString` containing the CSV data to a file using the `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` method.

2) Yes, in iOS 4 you can subscribe your app to certain file types, go [here](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH6-SW10) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've managed to send text (.txt) attachments using the addAttachmentData method you suggested, however I am unable to attach CSV files (see code below). An icon appears in the mail application indicating a textfile.csv attachment but when the message arrives there is no attachment at all (neither the data appears in the message body). I've tried changing mime type to text/plain but it does not work.